# The element 'XXXX' has invalid child element - xml issue

Tags: android, xml, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have just updated `Xamarin` and started getting the following issue in the xml.

Any one has any idea how to solve or handle this issue?

[image]

Comment: Post XML as text, formatted as code.   Never post XML or code in an image.

Comment: Did you tried to clean and rebuild the solution?

Comment: I have the same issue since a few updates and just kept ignoring it. Though a solution to get fully rid of the warning would be sweet.

Comment: It is not an issue, it is a false positive. Ignore it and continue focusing on other things...